# Laravel model is created with id = 0 after hosting

Tags: sql, laravel, model, cpanel, auto-increment

After hosting my Laravel project on cPanel, every time I create an user using Laravel default Register controller the Id becomes 0.
my migration:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_admin')->nullable();
            $table->string('dept');
            $table->string('batch');
            $table->string('roll');
            $table->integer('phone');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my controller:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'is_admin' => $data['is_admin'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' =>$data['email'],
            'phone' =>$data['phone'],
            'dept' => $data['dept'],
            'batch' =>$data['batch'],
            'roll' =>$data['roll'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['roll']),
            
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: its saving a 0 for 'id' in the database?

Comment: Yes, 
you are right.

Comment: There really isn't sufficient info provided, but a main suspicion of mine would be an incompatibility between Laravel and your database driver.

Comment: are you sure that your users table built with that exact migration?

Comment: yes, It is working in my local host. But it is not working after hosting in cPanel